# How do you create a new PowerPoint slide with text data from excel using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, export, powerpoint

I've tried just modifying code from existing forums, but it's designed for an existing powerpoint and I want to create a new powerpoint with the info from excel already populated. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong in my code?

```
Sub MarinePowerpoint()

Dim ws As Worksheet, wsB As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Overview")
Set wsB = Worksheets("Billing Rates")

Dim trueCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Cst, Hrs


For i = 1 To 11

If ws.Range(Chr(65 + i) & "36").Value = "True" Then
    trueCount = trueCount + 1
    Cst = Cst + wsB.Range(Chr(66 + i) & "33").Value
    Hrs = Hrs + wsB.Range(Chr(66 + i) & "25").Value
    Scope = Scope + wsB.Range(Chr(66 + i) & "150").Value
End If

Next i

If trueCount > 0 Then
trueCount = trueCount + 1
    Cst = Cst + wsB.Range(Chr(66 + i) & "33").Value
    Hrs = Hrs + wsB.Range(Chr(66 + i) & "25").Value
    Scope = Scope + wsB.Range(Chr(66 + i) & "150").Value
Data = "Cost: " & Cst _
& vbNewLine & "Hours: " & Hrs _
& vbNewLine & "Scope: " & Scope

'MsgBox Data
Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.Slides
Set PPApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
PPApp.Visible = True
Set PPPres = PPApp.Presentations.Add
PPPres.Range.Text = Data

End If

If trueCount = 0 Then
     MsgBox "Please select engagement components."
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Does any answer in [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/323408/excel-data-into-powerpoint-slides) help?

Comment: Unfortunately, not really :/ the data I'm trying to display is originally populating a message box in excel. I got some help figuring out how to export it to MS Word, but now I need to do the same thing but now in a powerpoint. Below is the original MS word code if it helps...

 Dim objWord
   Dim objDoc
   Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
   objWord.Visible = True
   objDoc.Range.Text = Data

Comment: PPPres.Range.Text = Data ... that's a problem there.  Presentations don't have a Range object so this line won't go anywhere.  After adding a presentation object, you'll need to add slides, then add text to the shapes collection of each slide.

Comment: Do you know where to find a basic code for adding a powerpoint slide slide, adding a shape(textbox), and then adding data to that powerpoint textbox? Most of the code I've found is for charts....and I'm not sure how to edit it to get it to work

Comment: See the answer I just posted

Answer (score 1):

Here's a bit of example code to add a shape with text:

```
Sub Example()

    Dim oSh As Shape

    ' On slide 1 of the currently active presentation:
    With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

        ' Add a rectangle at 100/100 left/top, 200/200 high and wide:
        ' Units are in points, 72 points = 1 inch
        Set oSh = .Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 100, 100, 200, 200)

        With oSh
            ' Ooo, let's make it bright red
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
            ' and some text:
            With .TextFrame.TextRange
                .Text = "Oooo, my face is red!"

                ' Format the text a bit:
                With .Font
                    .Name = "Arial"
                    .Color.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                    .Size = 36  ' points
                End With    ' Font

            End With    ' Textrange
        End With    ' Shape

    End With

End Sub
```